# Better way to create test objects from lookup tables?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, factory-boy

Is there a better way to create test objects to represent a PostgreSQL lookup table in a Django application?  I have three tables, the first of which is the User model from django.contrib.auth.models.  The second table is UserAccount which has a 1-to-1 relationship with User:

```
# models.py
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    user_type = models.ForeignKey('UserType')
```

The third table is the lookup table that has a 1-to-many relationship with UserAccount.  It stores the user types referenced by UserAccount and it is pre-populated with the three rows shown in the comments:

```
# models.py
class UserType(models.Model):
    user_type_cd = models.CharField(max_length=4)  # 'cpl', 'sm', 'sf'
    descrip = models.CharField(max_length=75)      # 'couple', 'single male', 'single female'
```

I'm using factory_boy to represent my test user:

```
# factories.py
import factory
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = User
    username = 'testuser'
    email = 'testuser@example.com'
    password = 'testpass'
```

Here is my test:

```
# model_tests.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase
from tests.signup.factories import UserFactory
from app.models import UserAccount, UserType

class TestUserAccountModel(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = UserFactory.build()
        self.user_type = UserType.objects.get(user_type_cd='cpl')  # <= hits the database!

    def test_valid_user_account(self):
        ua = UserAccount(user=self.user, user_type=self.user_type)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(ua, UserAccount))
```

The problem I have with this test is it runs slowly because I have to hit the database in the setUp to lookup the user type.  I can't represent the UserType class with a factory (I don't think) because it's already populated.  Is there a better way to construct this test, in particular one that will make it run faster?  This is supposed to be a unit test so I want it to run as fast as possible.  Thanks.

Comment: How you use user_type in test? Please give example, because current test will work even without it.

Comment: You are correct.  The test is as shown above but when I removed the user_type argument when setting ua in the test_valid_user_account, the test still passed, which I did not expect.  Thank you for pointing this out.